# Open a new window and get its location after loading

Tags: dom, dart, dart-html

I am using this code to open a new window:

```
Window w = window.open('example2.com', 'example2'); // Consisder than my domain
                                                    // is example1.com
```

This part of code works ok and succesfully opens a new window. Than i am trying to call my function after loading finishes.

```
w.onLoad.listen(locationGetter);
```

This is a code of locationGetter() function:

```
locationGetter(Event e) {
  Location currentLocation = w.location;
  currentHref = currentLocation.href; // currentHref is var defined
}                                    // in main() function
```

But this code doesn't work well. Every time when I run my script both currentLocation and currentHref is null. At the beginning i thought that problem was in onLoad event, so i tried to call w.location exacly after opening a window:

```
Window w = window.open('example2.com', 'example2');
Location currentLocation = w.location; // still null
```

I am pretty sure that both Window and WindowBase has location property. Please help me with my problem or provide alternative solution of this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a Dart issue.

Seems you run into this
http://blog.carbonfive.com/2012/08/17/cross-domain-browser-window-messaging-with-html5-and-javascript/

CORS prevents accessing windows of other domains, you can use postMessage instead.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. I thought that the page that my script opened is script-crossable cause i were able to run window.close(). I don't own server at different domain, so i will seek a different solution.